# Convert Twitter Timestamp in R

Tags: datetime, r

I am new to R and am terrible with handling dates.  The following date is returned from a query to the Twitter search API and is stored as a character string in a my dataframe.

> "Fri, 14 Jan 2011 03:01:22 +0000"

How can I convert this to a date and change the timezone to be Eastern Standard time?

I figure this is probably straight forward, but I dabbled with strptime and got nowhere.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What language are you using? — Update: nvm, I didn't realize that R was a language. Doh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me (I'm in the UK):

```
> ( str <- "Fri, 14 Jan 2011 03:01:22 +0000" )
[1] "Fri, 14 Jan 2011 03:01:22 +0000"

> ( str <- strptime(str, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", tz = "GMT") )
[1] "2011-01-14 03:01:22 GMT"

> ( dt.gmt <- as.POSIXct(str, tz = "GMT") )
[1] "2011-01-14 03:01:22 GMT"

> format(dt.gmt, tz = "EST", usetz = TRUE)
[1] "2011-01-13 22:01:22 EST"
```

Dates/times confuse me a lot, so I'm hoping the above works for you, even if you're in a different timezone from GMT, but I can't be sure!

Hope it helps a little at least,
Tony

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the help.  On my machine, the expression of the second command returns "NA" as I have received below.  As referenced for other answers, do you think it has to do with my locale settings?  I also am on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.12 and this code worked as expected (was on 2.10).  Was there something different between these two versions do you know?

Comment: @Btibert3 no idea what's changed between those two versions of R, but glad it worked for you mate. :)

Answer (score 6):

From the `help(strptime)`:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
[1] "C"
> strptime("Tue, 23 Mar 2010 14:36:38 -0400",
+          "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z",
+          tz="GMT")
[1] "2010-03-23 18:36:38 GMT"
```

Be careful about the locale: if you don't reset it to `C`, the function will try to parse weekday and month abbreviations as localized.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I tried to run your sample code, it evaluated to NA on my machine.  I even tried the same function call using my data and got the same thing.

Comment: At first I was getting NA too. Didn't you forget to reset the locale?

Comment: Yes, I ran your code and it didn't evaluate to the date, just NA.  thanks again for your help, just stumped.

Comment: @btibert3 let we try to resolve your confusion. What is your OS and locale?

Comment: Windows 7, and using Sys.locale(), I get: "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"

Comment: does `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` call succeed?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you take a look at Jeff Gentry's twitteR package on CRAN. Among other niceties, it parses date strings for you:

```
> library(twitteR)
> tweets = searchTwitter('#rstats')
> length(tweets)
[1] 25
> tweet = tweets[[1]]
> str(tweet)
Formal class 'status' [package "twitteR"] with 10 slots
  ..@ text        : chr "The Joy of Sweave \023 A Beginner\031s Guide to Reproducible Research with Sweave: Just& http://goo.gl/fb/APmCb #rstats"
  ..@ favorited   : logi FALSE
  ..@ replyToSN   : chr(0) 
  ..@ created     : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2011-01-18 04:48:05"
  ..@ truncated   : logi FALSE
  ..@ replyToSID  : num(0) 
  ..@ id          : num 2.72e+16
  ..@ replyToUID  : num(0) 
  ..@ statusSource: chr "&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&amp;answer=164577&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;"| __truncated__
  ..@ screenName  : chr "Rbloggers"
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I did see that and the package is terrific.  One thing that didn't work for me was the ID call to get the ID of the class 'status', which I need.  Does it work for you?  Although I am getting data from Twitter, I am using this as example of general date parsing.  Thx again.

Comment: oh, I see now that it treats the id as a float. Yeah -- that probably won't work that well...