# converting time in factor format into timestamp

Tags: r, time

I've downloaded tweets in json format, converted it into csv, and read it into R.  The existing time stamps are in factor format as shown below.  How should I convert it into a timestamp that can be plotted against?

```
[1] Fri May 09 07:55:12 +0000 2014 Fri May 09 07:55:12 +0000 2014 Fri May 09 07:55:12 +0000 2014
[4] Fri May 09 07:55:12 +0000 2014 Fri May 09 07:55:12 +0000 2014 Fri May 09 07:55:12 +0000 2014
516 Levels: Fri May 09 07:55:12 +0000 2014 ... Fri May 09 09:15:07 +0000 2014
```

Comment: Will something like `strptime(as.character(test$time_created), '%a %B %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')` work?

Comment: @tonytonov, you should probably post this as an answer for future readers

Comment: @tonytonov, thanks but it leads to multiple columns being created all filled with NAs.  Nonetheless, I've resolve the issue with Sven's solution below.

Comment: @eugeneyan It might be because May is still May after being abbreviated, so give it a shot with `%b` instead of `%B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the unnecessary parts of the string before applying `as.POSIXct`. This can be done with `gsub`:

```
x <-  as.factor(c("Fri May 09 07:55:12 +0000 2014", 
                  "Fri May 09 07:55:12 +0000 2014"))

as.POSIXct(gsub("^.+? | \\+\\d{4}","", x),
          format = "%b %d %X %Y")
# [1] "2014-05-09 07:55:12 CEST" "2014-05-09 07:55:12 CEST"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your question already answered => [Convert Twitter Timestamp in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696842/convert-twitter-timestamp-in-r)

But if you want to more simple you can use twitteR library.

```
> tweets <- userTimeline("BarackObama",n=100)
> df <- do.call("rbind",lapply(tweets, as.data.frame))
> names(df)
 [1] "text"          "favorited"     "favoriteCount" "replyToSN"     "created"       "truncated"    
 [7] "replyToSID"    "id"            "replyToUID"    "statusSource"  "screenName"    "retweetCount" 
[13] "isRetweet"     "retweeted"     "longitude"     "latitude"
```

we can plot directly the created status date